# How can I put my Extjs 4.2.x project inside latest Angular App

Tags: angular, extjs4, angular5, extjs4.1, extjs4.2

I have a large app built in Ext4.2.x. Now the requirement is to do further development in Angular.
I am trying to create a wrapper of Angular around Ext app so that we can use angular for further development/ migration of code piece by piece. till the time both the framework should work in harmony.

### Approach I am trying:

1. I have created app(name is: **NgApp**) scaffolding using **angular-cli** and put that code inside the root directory of Ext app(**ExtNg**).
2. Created a folder(**ExtNg/NgBuild**)to hold the build file of angular JS app(**NgApp**).
3. Built angular app : *ng build -vc false -op C:\Ext\Ext6Grid\ngBuild*
4. I have modified **app.js** `autCreateViewPort: false` so it will initiate the ext app but will not render it.
5. modified my Ext app's **index.html** body as below:

   `<body>
       <app-root></app-root>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="ngBuild/inline.bundle.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="ngBuild/polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="ngBuild/styles.bundle.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="ngBuild/main.bundle.js"></script>
   </body>`
6. Now I tried putting my Ext.onReady() code in *app.component.ts* class's ngOnInit() and specified `renderTo: someElemIDinAppComponentTemplate` method to start Ext inside an angular component.

So the problem here is as expected that while building angular app it does not find Ext object because Angular as framework dont know if Ext is there or not.

So could anyone help me getting `Ext` available inside my angular app's component?? 
So thought to share with all the geniuses out there.

I will be glad for any suggestions.
Thank you.

Comment: As far as I understood, while transpilation of Angular App, Ext references are not resolved and build is failing?

If so, have a look at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/global-lib.md

Basically, you will need to tweak process of creating a build by introducing gulp/shell script to first make an extjs build at sencha/build/ location and add the generated file path in angular-cli.json (one time adding) and then run angular cli build command.

That should make Ext resolvable while doing angular build.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are looking into this issue from the wrong angle. I suggest that you may build the angular app, and put yor ExtJS components inside that thing, not the opposite.

Here, you have an approximated approach of what you are trying to do : https://www.sencha.com/blog/first-look-ext-js-bridge-to-angular-2/

I want to believe "The Bridge" is also compatible with new Angular versions.

Comment: Hi Thanks for answering, but as per my knowledge Bridge is supporting Ext6+. and we are onto Ext4.2, Also we want a minimal change in our existing Ext code. so we are trying to put a wrapper of Angular around Ext so that Angular has control of the app.