# Invoke process of replacing <component-selector> to the <component-template> in angular 4

Tags: javascript, angular5, angular6, extjs4.2

How can we invoke process of replacing(which is invoked by angular at the start of app) component-selector with the component template html in angular 4. I want to work on Angular and Ext 4.2.2 together in my project. 
for more details you can refer [How can I put my Extjs 4.2.x project inside latest Angular App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48524407/how-can-i-put-my-extjs-4-2-x-project-inside-latest-angular-app). I am successfully able to integrate both the framework together. Now I want one of the new tab development in Angular instead of ExtJS. 
To get those two framework together I have gone through following steps:

1. I have put **root component selector** `<app-root>` inside
   `index.html` of Ext app.
2. I have initialized Ext app inside angular
   component's `ngOnInit` method.
3. Now My Ext app loads inside Angular component's template HTML.
4. Now inside Ext app I create a new **test** tab with Html containing a selector `app-panel` of one of the angular component.
5. When I click on the test tab `app-panel` is not replaced by component's template html.

   So I want this `app-panel` should work as normal angular component i.e. should be replaced with its associated template html. for this to work i have to invoke the process of replacing `app-panel` with its template. 
   Any genius out here might have done similar thing please let me know or just let me know your valuable suggestions on this. 
   Thanks in advance.

Comment: So in step 1, you put Angular inside ExtJS, and in step 2, you put ExtJS in Angular. Then in step 4, you put Angular inside ExtJS ... You should decide which one is the master and which one is the slave, I don't think this approach can work. Also, I would suggest ExtJS inside Angular, as Angualr change detection can include other things than its own context with `ngDoCheck`. Finally, I don't see the point of using two frameworks to do one thing, that either of them can do ... Can't you just chose one ?

Comment: Thanks @trichetriche. Actually I have a large app built in Ext4.2.x. Now the requirement is to do further development in Angular. I am trying to create a wrapper of Angular around Ext app so that we can use angular for further development/ migration of code piece by piece. till the time both the framework should work in harmony. Please let me know if you know a better solution to this problem.